# Is newsgroup comp.lang.c++.moderated dead?

Tags: c++, newsgroup

According to what Google shows one the newsgroup [`comp.lang.c++.moderated`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.c++.moderated) the last post is almost a year old now (it is from 23th May 2016).

I wrote a post myself almost a week ago and it wasn't published so far.

At the same time newsgroup [`comp.lang.c++`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.c++) is still active (with posts from today).

Is the [`comp.lang.c++.moderated`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.c++.moderated) officially closed now? Is there any replacement for it (other than [`comp.lang.c++`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.c++))?

Comment: Not a question for stack overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about programming.

Comment: Where should it be asked then?

Comment: I think the question could qualify for the "software tools commonly used by programmers" scope listed by http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Why not ask comp.lang.c++?

Comment: @jotik Good point! Why haven't I thought about that? It seems I'm used to much to StackOverflow... Anyway I did ask just now: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++/OGoy0g1IdmQ

Comment: I only just spotted this question now: I'm, well was, one of the moderators of comp.lang.c++.moderated and, yes, the group - sadly - dead. Activity kind of went down over some period and eventually we lost the ability to inject new articles. We weren't even able to post a final "Thank you all for a great time!" post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by jotik in comments to the question I asked the same question on [`comp.lang.c++`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.c++): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++/OGoy0g1IdmQ

From answers there it seems that `*.moderated` groups in general are kind of closed as the moderation framework failed.